# fixed header will not scroll horizontally with body

Tags: html, css, image

I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix this.  i have made a fixed header and only the content box would scroll but if i scroll horizontally the header will stay in the middle of the browser and my content will scroll around which makes it look pretty dumb.  I want both vertical and horizontal scrolling too.

Does anyone know how to fix this with just pure css html?? =X

Please help!

I'm not allowed to post pictures here yet so go to www.covenantchurch-pca.net and scroll horizontally & you will see my problem.  If you need to see my html css coding plz tell me .  I really need the help.  I'm not so great at this.

Comment: Consider creating a JSFiddle so we can easily fork and tinker...

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DJcode/4wrGL/1/)

hope this is what you are talking about.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<img style="position: fixed; height:200px; width:40px; top: 150px;right: 0px;" id="imgId" src="images/skin/contact2.png">
```

this will work for you ..